# Graphing using derivatives

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Sketch the graph of the following equation. Show steps of finding out critical numbers, intervals of increase and decrease, absolute maximum and minimum values and concavity.

$$y= xe^{x^2}$$

I found the first derivative which is $y'=(2x^2 + 1)e^{x^2}$ and I know that in order to find min and max the zeroes for $y'$ must be found, but $y'$ doesn't have any real zeroes, and I'm confused about how to go on with solving the problem.

If someone could help me out, that would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x)=xe^{x^2}$, then $f'(x)=2x^2e^{x^2}+e^{x^2}=e^{x^2}(2x^2+1)$, as you have written.

Since the derivative never equals zero or is undefined across the domain, you can conclude there are no critical numbers and no relative extrema.

Can you show that the function is always increasing by showing that $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$?

To determine the concavity of the function, you must now find $f''(x)$. Can you proceed?

Comment: So, I don't need to make a sign chart, right? 
And how do I show that f'(x) > 0 zero for all numbers, do I just plug in random numbers from both the negative and positive side into f'(x)? 
And, yes, I think I can do the concavity part on my own. 

Thank you so much!

Comment: For this particular example, making a sign chart will be rather unhelpful because you don't have any points at which $f'(x)=0$ to base the chart off of! You can show that the derivative is always positive by noting that $e^{x^2}$ is always positive and $(2x^2+1)$ is also always positive. Thus, any product of those two is also positive! You're very welcome, and please ask more questions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have discovered that the function is increasing, because its derivative is positive, so the function has no maximum nor minimum.

Compute also
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}xe^{x^2}=-\infty,
\qquad
\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{x^2}=\infty,
$$
and note there's no oblique asymptote.

For concavity and convexity, compute the second derivative
$$
f''(x)=4xe^{x^2}+(2x^2+1)\cdot 2xe^{x^2}=2(2x^3+3x)e^{x^2}
$$
The second derivative only vanishes at $0$.